# Free Offline Map Provider (and not OpenStreetMap)

Tags: android

I am making for my Graduation Project a **low price** Navigation device, using Android as Operating System

I tried the Native Google's Map-view Control, but it works only Online ..
and of-course I want to store maps for offline navigation

So.. I want a map provider (like OpenStreetMap) that :

- I can use offline
- Contain Searchable Street names (not only a rendered image)
- for commercial use
- Free or at low price

The problem with OpenStreetMap that it doesn't provide detailed map for most cities in Egypt.

Comment: You want both 'free' and 'for commercial use', i.e. someone should invest money to develop something that you get for free and then sell to people? Short of an open-source project like OpenStreetMaps, you won't find anything. And you can always contribute Egyptian street maps - that is the purpose of that project.

Comment: And he also wants all of it to work offline, esp on the android? good luck with that man. 

You're better off creating an android app for storing OpenStreetMaps Images and using it offline for ur grad proj.

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy: Android is free .. although I can sell device uses Android
anyway .. I said free **or at low price** .. as my Project focuses on Low Cost

Comment: @Shawn Mclean
I already know a Free programs that do download OSM for offline usage .. like contentDroid ... but the OSM itself is poor in Egypt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net).

Comment: Mobile Atlas Creator uses OpenStreetMap and Google map data. It violates both license and usage terms. Please don't use this app!

Answer (score 3):

You want something like MapDroyd, maybe talk to them about using their code.

Alternatively take the OpenStreetMap widget from here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/
and add a way to cache regions. For the street name index you can download the world.osm (or just part of it to save time) and then run it through a python script like this:

(Note that this needs some work: it doesn't handle duplicate street names, so you'll have to modify it a bit. It also finds pubs and ATMs.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from xml.dom import pulldom

doc = pulldom.parse("england.osm")
#outFile = open("england.txt", "w")

nodes = {}
ways = {}
pubs = []
atms = []

i = 0
for event, node in doc:
    if event == pulldom.START_ELEMENT:
        if node.localName == "node":
            doc.expandNode(node)

            nodeID = node.getAttribute("id")
            nodeLat = node.getAttribute("lat")
            nodeLon = node.getAttribute("lon")

            amenity = "";
            for tag in node.getElementsByTagName("tag"):
                if tag.getAttribute("k") == "amenity":
                    amenity = tag.getAttribute("v")

            nodes[int(nodeID)] = ( float(nodeLat), float(nodeLon) )

            if amenity == "pub":
                pubs.append(int(nodeID))
            elif amenity == "atm" or amenity == "bank":
                atms.append(int(nodeID))

        elif node.localName == "way":
            doc.expandNode(node)

            name = "";
            for tag in node.getElementsByTagName("tag"):
                if tag.getAttribute("k") == "name":
                    name = tag.getAttribute("v")
            if name == "":
                continue;

            wayName = name.encode("latin-1", "replace")
            refList = [nd.getAttribute("ref") for nd in node.getElementsByTagName("nd")]

            if ways.has_key(wayName):
                ways[wayName].append([int(x) for x in refList])
            else:
                ways[wayName] = [int(x) for x in refList]

        i = i + 1
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print(i / 100)

print(nodes)
print(ways)
print(pubs)
print(atms)

#outFile.close()
```

Comment: MapDroyd uses Maps from OSM
and OSM itself doesn't provide detailed maps in most cities Egypt

The Question is about provider other than OSM
even if it has no API to deal with in Android , I can do whatever it takes to make this works on Android

Comment: Sounds like more of a business question than a programming one then. You might want to try ask on a mapping forum rather than stackoverflow.

I seriously doubt there will be any free map providers other than OSM.